# Why a mail sending from word/excel/... gets stuck in the outbox when Outlook is closed?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

This problem is permanent and happens to me ONLY when Outlook is closed.

1. I open Excel (or other product that have the capacity to send mails) and I type something in it, then I send this content by mail, to somebody.
2. From task manager I can see how Outlook "wakes up" and seems to catch the mail to send but it doesn't send. The message gets stuck in the "outbox", and it should not.
3. Only when I open Outlook manually, the message is sent immediately.

What is wrong here? Is it a configuration problem in my Outlook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug, Outlook just doesn't send messages from the outbox until you open the main window.

This might work from http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_send_now.htm:

> - Select Tools | Options... from the menu in Outlook.
> - Go to the Mail Setup tab.
> - Make sure Send immediately when connected in checked.
> - Click OK.

It's supposed to work with Outlook 2007, however a similar option might be available for Outlook 2010.

**Update:**

For Outlook 2010 and 2013: Click the orange button with "File" in the top left, go to Options, Advanced and make sure "Send immediately when connected" is checked under "Send and receive".

Comment: Yes, you are right. Outlook needs to be permanently open. The reason of the question is that my boss needed an urgent document which I sent directly from Excel, but I didn't realize that my Outlook was closed, so the mail never was sent until I opened it :-(. Anyway, thanks for your additional info. My best regards.

Comment: To save anyone else the bother - this fix doesn't work and the issue is still present in 2013. (I have two customers with 2010 and 2013 who both have the problem)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same intermittent problem here.  The client was in Cached Exchange Mode, so I switched her over and it started working.  Try taking Outlook out of Cached Exchange Mode, restart Outlook, then try again.